# variable that conforms to protocol to accept variables that conform to protocol

Tags: swift, swift3

I have a variable that is of type ProtocolItem1 protocol inside Item class. what I would like to do is be able to use this class and also save objects that conform to the ProtocolItem1 protocol in this variable, is this possible? I know in java you can create an interface, and implement it this way. In objective C I ve seen id, Please let me know.

Code:

```
class Item : NSObject {
    var obj: ProtocolItem1?

    //Other functions and variables
}

class Item2: ProtocolItem1 {
    //variables and methods
}

class OtherClass: UIViewController {
    var dataSource: Item
    //other functions
    override func viewDidLoad(){
       var object1: Item2 = Item2()
       dataSource.obj = object1
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer: yes.**

In Swift you can create a property with a protocol type. Any object can be assigned to that property as long as it conforms to the specified protocol.

The following slightly modified version of your code is valid Swift.

```
protocol ProtocolItem1 {}

class Item: NSObject {
    var obj: ProtocolItem1?
}

class Item2: ProtocolItem1 {}

class OtherClass: UIViewController {

    var dataSource: Item?

    override func viewDidLoad(){
        let object1 = Item2()
        dataSource?.obj = object1
    }

}
```